# how to align flexbox items in last row to the left

Tags: css, flexbox

There are many similar solutions but I really cannot get it work here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jglabb/os76bytq/2/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="item">
  item 1
</div>
<div class="item">
  item 2
</div>
<div class="item">
  item 3
</div>
<div class="item">
  item 4
</div>
<div class="item">
  item 5
</div>
<div class="item">
  item 6
</div>
<div class="item">
  item 7
</div>
</div>

.container {
  width: 240px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  row-gap: 7px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

So regardless of container width and number of rows - I want to align left whatever left in the last row

Comment: .container .item:last-child {text-align:left;}

Comment: it's not working

Comment: I do not know. at least I know the container size if that helps. Ideally it would align items in last row even if I resize the container.